# Playing a Youtube video doesn't prevent the screensaver from starting!

Tags: video, youtube, screensaver, gnome-screensaver

After doing updates through **Software and Updates**, playing a full screen YouTube video doesn't prevent the screensaver from starting anymore. Before it worked fine.

VLC works fine. It only starts when playing videos online (not just Youtube) - could it be **Flash player**?

Also **Caffeine** is not working either in this case, but otherwise it works - it will prevent the screensaver from starting, but not when playing full screen video. I don't understand what could be wrong and how to resolve this issue!

Comment: Do you have YouTube set to use Flash or HTML5?  I've had HTML5 set for a long time, and I've seen this same behavior for a long time, but other video sources play without screen saver starting.  Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, so probably HTML5